# Convex quadrilateral with interior point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral and $X$ is an interior point.

Also let $AX\cap BD=\{E\}$, $BX\cap AC=\{F\}$, $CX\cap BD=\{G\}$ and $DX\cap AC=\{H\}$.

Prove that:

$$AF\cdot BG\cdot CH\cdot DE=AH\cdot BE\cdot CF\cdot DG$$

I proved it by the following ugly reasoning.

Let $AC\cap BD=\{O\}$, $AH:HO:OC=x:y:z$ and $BO:OG:GD=a:b:c$.

Hence, by Thales we can get that:

$$\frac{AF}{AH}\cdot\frac{CH}{CF}=\frac{(x+y)(y+z)(a+b)(b+c)}{acy(x+y+z)+(a+b)(b+c)xz}$$
and
$$\frac{BG}{BE}\cdot\frac{GE}{DG}=\frac{xzb(a+b+c)+(x+y)(y+z)ac}{(x+y)(y+z)(a+b)(b+c)}$$

and we are done.

Is there something easy here?

Thank you!

Comment: That identity can be proved by dealing with a ratio of cross-ratios (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio)

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio It's an eighth grade. 13-14 y.

Comment: Then it is a tough problem for an eigth grade, with an elementary solution in terms of cross ratios.

Comment: have a look at (forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2006volume6/FG200626.pdf)